# How to start automatically animation at page load on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to implement a splash screen page in my app. I need to start automatically the animation when page is showed but the actual implementation does not work. The animation isn't executed on page open.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:coin_flip_app/home_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class SplashScreenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashScreenPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenPageState createState() => _SplashScreenPageState();
}

class _SplashScreenPageState extends State<SplashScreenPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), value: 1);

    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          ));
    });

    _controller.forward().then((f) {
      _controller.reverse();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 48, 48, 48),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RotationTransition(
              turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_controller),
              child: SizedBox(
                child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/app_logo.svg'),
                height: 150,
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "My App",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 32,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I try to invoke the animation with a `onTap()` event with GestureDetector it works. But I need that it starts and complete without user input but automatically.

**UPDATE #1**

This is the updated code. It is also not working. It works only uncommenting the first `// await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));` but I think it is only a workaround but not the final solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:coin_flip_app/home_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class SplashScreenPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SplashScreenPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenPageState createState() => _SplashScreenPageState();
}

class _SplashScreenPageState extends State<SplashScreenPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), value: 1);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) => loopOnce(context)); //i add this to access the context safely.
  }

  Future<void> loopOnce(BuildContext context) async {
    // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    await _controller.forward();
    await _controller.reverse();
    //we can add duration here
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      // since this triggers when the animation is done, no duration is needed
      builder: (context) => HomePage(),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 48, 48, 48),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RotationTransition(
              turns: _controller,
              child: SizedBox(
                child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/app_logo.svg'),
                height: 150,
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "My App",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 32,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this work if you remove the .then((f) => _controller.reverse()) ?

Comment: No it doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weird, maybe try using

`_controller.repeat(reverse: true);`

instead of

```
_controller.forward().then((f) {
      _controller.reverse();
    });
```

oh and don't forget to dispose

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

and you can use this directly

```
RotationTransition(
              turns:_controller,
              child: SizedBox(
                child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/app_logo.svg'),
                height: 150,
              ),
            ),
```

EDIT:

So if i understood correctly you want to do this

Loop forward an then backwards once,
when the loop it's finished , navigate to a screen.

My method would be this one

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250), value: 1);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_)=>loopOnce(context));//i add this to access the context safely.
  }

  Future<void> loopOnce(BuildContext context)async{
    await _controller.forward();
    await _controller.reverse();
    //we can add duration here 
    //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute( // since this triggers when the animation is done, no duration is needed
            builder: (context) => HomePage(),
          ));
  }
```

EDIT 2:

```
class Loader extends StatefulWidget {
  const Loader();
  @override
  _LoaderState createState() => _LoaderState();
}

class _LoaderState extends State<Loader> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500), value: 0);

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
        (_) => loopOnce(context)); //i add this to access the context safely.
  }

  Future<void> loopOnce(BuildContext context) async {
    // await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    await _controller.forward();
    await _controller.reverse();
    //we can add duration here
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 48, 48, 48),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RotationTransition(
              turns: _controller,
              child: Container(
                width: 150,
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 150,
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text(
                "Coin Flip",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 32,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
}
}
```

Comment: I tried to use `_controller.repeat(reverse: true)` but it rotates indefinitely. Is there a way to specify only one rotation?

Comment: It does not work, the animation is not executed. It seems like we are ask to execute animation before the page is ready. Adding an `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));` before await `_controller.forward();` in your last suggested code it works but I think it is not the correct method

Comment: ' WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback' is a function that is executed the first frame of build , so the page should be ready and the context should be complete... Could you please post the current code that you are using below , it might be a device problem but i can test it to check where it's failing

Comment: Yep , it may be a hardware problem , https://gfycat.com/spiritedneedydore , the only thing that i changed is the duration, the initial value to 0 , and the svg, check the edit

Comment: It works! The problem was related to `value:1` and my `reverse()/forward()` usage. If value is 0 you need to call `forward()` and then `reverse()`, if value is 1 you need to invert them. Both my first code and your code work perfectly using this rules, Flutter documentation is not clear about it. I will use your suggested code to be sure access the context safely.

Comment: Yeah that little context hack is everywhere in my code, i use it for navigation, data , etc etc . I'm glad it worked!